# Convert String in Int

Tags: java, string

In my private void jButtonOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
I have error message:

### incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int

My first field (IdentCat) is normaly an Int.
However I don't know how to do this in INT ?

```
ap.setIdentCat(jTextIdent.getText().toUpperCase());
```

More of code

```
private void jButtonOKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Categorie ap = new Categorie();
        ap.setIdentCat(jTextIdent.getText().toUpperCase());
        ap.setDenomCat(jTextDescr.getText());

        boolean ok = daoCat.insertCategorie(ap);
        if (!ok)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Insertion impossible !","Avertissement",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        this.dispose();
    }
```

Comment: You can’t pass a string value where an int is required. You need to call the ParseInt function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert a String to an int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-do-i-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Integer.parseInt("123456")`.

Comment: like that ???

ap.setIdentCat (Integer.parseInt (jTextIdent.getText ()));

Comment: You should do some error handling too like what if 23k comes in. The String so according to me you should first check string.isDigit then do parseInt

Answer (score 3):

Use `Integer.valueOf("string")` as alternative too! This will return an Integer object.

```
String number = "10";
Integer result = Integer.valueOf(number);
```